# Issues removing an "<li>" using e.target.parentElement.remove()

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, addeventlistener

I am creating a To Do list and am trying to remove an li line after the remove button has been clicked. With the code I have now, nothing happens when the remove button has been clicked. Is it an issue with the parent element? the li is the parent element, not the input, correct?

Also, please disregard the checkbox input in the HTML. I have not written the JS code for the checkbox's function yet. Thank you!

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

todolist.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName === 'button'){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>To Do List:</h1>
     <ul id="todolist"></ul>
         <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Grocery Shop <button type=button class=button>Remove</button><br></li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Workout <button type=button class=button>Remove</button><br></li>
     <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
        <input type="text" id="theToDo" 
        name="addToDo" 
        placeholder="Add to the list here">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>    
    </ul><br>
  <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `ul` end tag was in the wrong place.
2. Changed the case of the `tagName` to upper case.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

todolist.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>To Do List:</h1>
    <ul id="todolist">
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Grocery Shop <button type=button class=button>Remove</button><br></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Workout <button type=button class=button>Remove</button><br></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
        <input type="text" id="theToDo" name="addToDo" placeholder="Add to the list here">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </ul><br>
    <script src=Test.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are adding the event listener to the `#todolist`. There's no need to do this. You can add the event listener directly to the `<button>` elements by using the following:

```
onclick="remove(event)"
```

And adding a `remove` function to process the click. See the code snippet...

```js
function remove(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>To Do List:</h1>
    <ul id="todolist"></ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Grocery Shop 
          <button type=button class=button onclick="remove(event)">Remove</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Workout 
          <button type=button class=button onclick="remove(event)">Remove</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
          <input type="text" id="theToDo" 
            name="addToDo" 
            placeholder="Add to the list here">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problem.

The first is that there is an extra `</ul>`in the `<ul id="todolist"></ul>`, because the ul in the `</ul><br>` should pair with the `<ul>`.

The second is that the class usage is wrong, you could use the in this way `e.target.classList.contains('button')`

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue was that you were immediately closing your given `#todolist` UL, so none of the events were firing. Also, unless I am totally mistaken (I've not paid attention so I could be wrong), I believe the value of `$el.tagName` (where `$el` is a DOM Node) is going to be uppercase, i.e. `BUTTON`.

Otherwise, I would use the [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) function.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

todolist.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#todolist li button')) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>To Do List:</h1>
<ul id="todolist">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Grocery Shop <button type=button class=button>Remove</button></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Workout <button type=button class=button>Remove</button></li>
  <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
    <input type="text" id="theToDo" name="addToDo" placeholder="Add to the list here">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</ul>
```